# How to set a string value into varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I'm trying to set a string into a `varbinary` without converting its value.

Example:

```
declare @string varchar(max)

set @string='0x7777'

update tablename
set Data=@string
```

I know this is not possible since it's not allowed. However I don't wanna convert the string to `varbinary` (using `select CONVERT(varbinary(max),@string`)) since it'll result in saving:

```
0x307837373737
```

Also, I know that making `@string varbinary` and removing ' 's would fix the problem, however that's not what I'm looking for since I'm working with strings in order to save it inside a `varbinary`.

I want the output to be: `0x7777` inside the `varbinary`

Thank you.

Comment: So want to parse a hex-string to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use CONVERT, just pass 3rd parameter.

```
update tablename
set Data=convert(varbinary(max), @string, 1)
```

> *If the data_type is a binary type, the expression must be a character
>   expression. The expression must be composed of an even number of
>   hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, a,
>   b, c, d, e, f). If the style is set to 1 the characters 0x must be the
>   first two characters in the expression. If the expression contains an
>   odd number of characters or if any of the characters are invalid an
>   error is raised.*

See [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for binary styles conversion.